# Weaning myself off unhealthy cereal

Tags: diet, food, breakfast

In general, I'm comfortable with my diet. The one thing I'm conscious of is the fact that I eat the same chocolate breakfast cereal (Weetos) every day (and I mean **every** day.) It's been like that for as long as I can remember (I'm 18.) I'd like to wean myself off it eventually so I'm eating healthier breakfasts. The problem isn't just willpower, but culinary - I don't know what else is good to eat in the morning because I invariably eat sugary cereal. So I'm asking two questions:

1) How can I make myself eat less of this cereal?

2) What are healthy, tasty, minimum effort alternatives for breakfast?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that you can't really eat a worse (as in worse for you) breakfast. :)

If you're eating sugary cereals it will probably take a while to get your brain used to the idea that it's not getting a sugar bomb when you wake up, but there are a lot of things you can eat for breakfast that taste sweet, but have some benefits.

To stay away from sugary cereals but still have something sweet try eating yogurt, fruit, toast with some form of jam (eat it with peanut butter to get a little fat and protein in your breakfast), or cereal that's better for you but also a little bit sweetened (any number of flavored Cheerios, etc).

If you are willing to put a little bit more effort into your breakfast, a scrambled egg with a handful of cheese (and maybe some shredded ham or pre-cooked sausage) only takes 5-10 minutes to prepare and is a much more solid breakfast. It will make you feel more satisfied than sugary foods and will stick with you longer though the day.

Comment: "The good news is that you can't really eat a worse (as in worse for you) breakfast." I'm not sure how this could be seen as good news xD. I could do with more eggs. Are poached or boiled any worse than scrambled?

Comment: I'm not a fan of plain eggs. So if I have eggs I want them in a way that I can add some flavor in the form of meat and cheese. Health-wise I honestly don't know if there are differences.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the cereals loaded with chocolate you could opt for the Cornflakes kind of breakfast and top it with fruits which you like the most(do not mix sugar again in the milk). Go for muesli if fresh fruits are not available but make sure the muesli contain the fruit but not the  added flavour and very less sugar content.

This will definitely wean you off your cereal habit and also give your body the required energy for the day plus the taste of the fruits.

Follow this breakfast regime for atleast 2-3 weeks and you will see the result for your self.

Comment: I kinda don't feel like this adds anything that @alesplin's answer didn't mention in greater detail.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla goodness of corn with added fruits  and moreover I cannot comment right now so added it as an answer.

Comment: @user286oo6: I'd rather have put it as a comment too, but you're right... we have that stupid comment-block in place, which I tend to forget all about. Still not sure if 'tricking' the system by posting an answer instead is the way to go...

Comment: Its just to help the owner who posted it and there's nothing tricky here as if  the user likes the answer and seems fit then he upvotes it or simply down-vote.